# Assignment problem worker/task with python - ortools

Tags: python, optimization, variable-assignment, or-tools, cp-sat

I have a table like this, in which rows represent the tasks (5) and the columns the workers (3).

```
   |  w1 |  w2 | w3
--------------------
t1 |  90 |  76 | 75
t2 |  35 |  85 | 55
t3 | 125 |  95 | 90
t4 |  45 | 110 | 95
t5 |  60 | 105 | 80
```

always --> #tasks > #workers

The values are the "affinity" score between a worker and a task

I have to assign a task t* to a worker w* **maximizing the sum** of the chosen task scores

- A worker may have multiple tasks and must have at least one task
- A task can only be assigned once

Possibile solution (not the best, a random one):

```
w1: [t2, t3] 35 + 125 = 160
w2: [t1]              = 76
w3: [t4, t5] 95 + 80  = 175
```

Furthermore these is also this constraint: each task s* has a size
`sizes = [10, 8, 14, 18, 13]  # (len(sizes) = number of rows)`

and the ideal overall size that a worker should get is
`ideal_size_per_worker = [15, 20, 18]  # (len(ideal_size_per_worker) = number of columns)`

In this case I want to **minimize the absolute error given by the sum of the task sizes and the ideal size**.
Given the previous solution

```
w1: [t2, t3] 8 + 14  = 22 -> minimize(abs(22 - 15))
w2: [t1]             = 10 -> minimize(abs(10 - 20))
w3: [t4, t5] 18 + 13 = 31 -> minimize(abs(31 - 18))
```

I'm using `ortools.cp_model` (is the right solver for this problem?)
I got stuck implementing the second constraint, having problem defining the absolute difference

The code so far:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

data = [
    [90, 76, 75], 
    [35, 85, 55], 
    [125, 95, 90], 
    [45, 110, 95], 
    [60, 105, 80]
]

n_tasks = len(data)
n_workers = len(data[0])

# Variables
x = {}
for task in range(n_tasks):
    for worker in range(n_workers):
        x[task, worker] = model.NewBoolVar(f'x[{task},{worker}]')

# Each task is assigned to exactly one worker.
for task in range(n_tasks):
    model.AddExactlyOne(x[task, worker] for worker in range(n_workers))

# Each worker takes at least 1 task
for worker in range(n_workers):
    model.AddAtLeastOne(x[task, worker] for task in range(n_tasks))


# Objective, maximize the score sums
objective_terms = []
for task in range(n_tasks):
    for worker in range(n_workers):
        objective_terms.append(scores[task][worker] * x[task, worker])
model.Maximize(sum(objective_terms))


# # stuck here... model. ... Minimize absolute error


# Solve
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

# Print solution.
if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
    print(f'Total score = {solver.ObjectiveValue()}\n')
    for task in range(n_tasks):
        for worker in range(n_workers):
            if solver.BooleanValue(x[task, worker]):
                print(f'task {task} assigned to worker {worker}.' +
                      f' Score = {data[task][worker]}')
else:
    print('No solution found.')
```

Comment: for the second objective you can create one abs_error var per worker and use `AddAbsEquality(error[w], sum(...) - ideal_size_per_worker[w])`, you also have to think about how you want to deal with the multiple objectives though

Comment: ok thanks,  but how do you define the variable error? is a cp_model variable or just a python dictionary? because it seems it should be a model variable

Comment: yeah, they have to be new intvars